# How to pass a class to database migration?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class that describes a person:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have two classes that inherit this `Person` class and each of them has just one different property.

I'm going to create a migration and I have to set some attributes for properties in these classes, but I don't need to add `Person` class to the database. How can I do it?

Can I set the attributes in `Person` class, inherit it but pass it in migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this fits your needs! If you don't want the `Person` class in the database, just leave it out of the DbContext. And if you find yourself needing to tweak configurations for each child class, the ideal solution is to use `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. I've included an example below to help you out.

Define a base class 'Person' with common properties.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Create a derived class 'ChildPerson1' that inherits from 'Person'.
Add a specific property 'FavoriteToy' to this class.

```
  public class ChildPerson1 : Person
{
    public string? FavoriteToy { get; set; }
}
```

Create another derived class 'ChildPerson2' that inherits from 'Person'.
Add a specific property 'Surname' to this class.

```
  public class ChildPerson2 : Person
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Define a database context 'PersonDbContext' that inherits from DbContext.
Include DbSet properties for each derived class.
Apply configurations using the 'OnModelCreating' method.

```
public class PersonDbContext : DbContext
{
   public PersonDbContext(DbContextOptions<PersonDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<ChildPerson1> ChildPerson1s => Set<ChildPerson1>();
   public DbSet<ChilPerson2> ChilPerson2s => Set<ChilPerson2>();

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
    
      modelBuilder
     .ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(PersonDbContext).Assembly);
   }

}
```

Define a configuration class 'ChildPerson1Configurations' that implements 'IEntityTypeConfiguration'.
Configure specific properties for the 'ChildPerson1' entity.

```
 public class ChildPerson1Configurations : 
 IEntityTypeConfiguration<ChildPerson1>
 {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ChildPerson1> builder)
        {
            // Additional configurations specific to ChildPerson1.
            // For example, set the maximum length for the 'FavoriteToy' property.
            builder.Property(p => p.FavoriteToy).HasMaxLength(50);
    
            // Change the column name for the 'FirstName' property.
            builder.Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("First_Name");
        

    
       }
}
```

Add ChildPerson2Configurations if needed.